# PHP Merge / Combine Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i'm having below multidimensional array,

```
Array
(
    [address] => Array
        (
            [1] => skdbabsdkbakbskjabsd 
            [2] => skbdskbdkjbskjdbkjsb ksbdk bsdkb
        )

    [contact] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1236547890
            [2] => 654654654646464
        )

)
```

How to convert / merge into something like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => skdbabsdkbakbskjabsd 
            [2] => 1236547890
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => skbdskbdkjbskjdbkjsb ksbdk bsdkb
            [2] => 654654654646464
        )

)
```

As mentioned below i'm trying to combine first address 1 with contact 1 similarly address 2 to contact 2 and so on..

Any solution to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is link for the code](https://eval.in/159389)

```
$address= Array
(
    "address" => Array
        (
            "skdbabsdkbakbskjabsd",
            "skbdskbdkjbskjdbkjsb ksbdk bsdkb"
        ),

    "contact" => Array
        (
            1236547890,
            6546546
        )

);


$result= array();
$i = 0;
foreach($address['address'] as $key => $value){
    $result[$i][] = $value;
    $result[$i][] = $address['contact'][$key];
    $i++;
}
echo '<pre>';
  print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the numerical keys, I would do this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($address as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = array($address[$key], $contact[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('adress' => array('1' => 'skdbabsdkbakbskjabsd', 
                                '2' => 'skbdskbdkjbskjdbkjsb ksbdk bsdkb'),
              'contact' => array('1' => '1236547890', 
                                 '2' => '654654654646464'));
echo '<pre>';    

print_r($data);

$mergedArray = array();
foreach($data['adress'] as $key => $adress){
    $mergedArray[] = array(1 => $adress, 2 => $data['contact'][$key]);
}


print_r($mergedArray);

echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [adress] => Array
        (
            [1] => skdbabsdkbakbskjabsd
            [2] => skbdskbdkjbskjdbkjsb ksbdk bsdkb
        )

    [contact] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1236547890
            [2] => 654654654646464
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => skdbabsdkbakbskjabsd
            [2] => 1236547890
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => skbdskbdkjbskjdbkjsb ksbdk bsdkb
            [2] => 654654654646464
        )

)
```